# How to define a loss function in pytorch with dependency to partial derivatives of the model w.r.t input?

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, ode

After reading about how to solve an ODE with neural networks following the paper [Neural Ordinary Differential Equations](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.07366) and the [blog](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-solve-an-ode-with-a-neural-network-917d11918932) that uses the library JAX I tried to do the same thing with "plain" Pytorch but found a point rather "obscure": How to properly use the partial derivative of a function (in this case the model) w.r.t one of the input parameters.

To resume the problem at hand as shown in [2](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-solve-an-ode-with-a-neural-network-917d11918932) it is intended to solve the ODE y' = -2*x*y with the condition y(x=0) = 1 in the domain -2 <= x <= 2. Instead of using finite differences the solution is replaced by a NN as y(x) = NN(x) with a single layer with 10 nodes.

I managed to (more or less) replicate the blog with the following code

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch import optim
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 

# Define the NN model to solve the problem
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.lin1 = nn.Linear(1,10)
        self.lin2 = nn.Linear(10,1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.sigmoid(self.lin1(x))
        x = torch.sigmoid(self.lin2(x))
        return x

model = Model()

# Define loss_function from the Ordinary differential equation to solve
def ODE(x,y):
    dydx, = torch.autograd.grad(y, x, 
    grad_outputs=y.data.new(y.shape).fill_(1),
    create_graph=True, retain_graph=True)

    eq = dydx + 2.* x * y # y' = - 2x*y
    ic = model(torch.tensor([0.])) - 1.    # y(x=0) = 1
    return torch.mean(eq**2) + ic**2

loss_func = ODE

# Define the optimization
# opt = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.1, momentum=0.99,nesterov=True) # Equivalent to blog
opt = optim.Adam(model.parameters(),lr=0.1,amsgrad=True) # Got faster convergence with Adam using amsgrad

# Define reference grid 
x_data = torch.linspace(-2.0,2.0,401,requires_grad=True)
x_data = x_data.view(401,1) # reshaping the tensor

# Iterative learning
epochs = 1000
for epoch in range(epochs):
    opt.zero_grad()
    y_trial = model(x_data)
    loss = loss_func(x_data, y_trial)

    loss.backward()
    opt.step()

    if epoch % 100 == 0:
        print('epoch {}, loss {}'.format(epoch, loss.item()))

# Plot Results
plt.plot(x_data.data.numpy(), np.exp(-x_data.data.numpy()**2), label='exact')
plt.plot(x_data.data.numpy(), y_data.data.numpy(), label='approx')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

From here I manage to get the results as shown in the fig.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jp4a.png)

The problems is that at the definition of the ODE functional, instead of passing (x,y) I would rather prefer to pass something like (x,fun) (where fun is my model) such that the partial derivative and specific evaluations of the model can be done with a call . So, something like

```py
def ODE(x,fun):
    dydx, = "grad of fun w.r.t x as a function"

    eq = dydx(x) + 2.* x * fun(x)        # y' = - 2x*y
    ic = fun( torch.tensor([0.]) ) - 1.  # y(x=0) = 1
    return torch.mean(eq**2) + ic**2
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

**EDIT**:

After some trials I found a way to pass the model as an input but found another strange behavior... The new problem is to solve the ODE y'' = -2 with the BC y(x=-2) = -1 and y(x=2) = 1, for which the analytical solution is y(x) = -x^2+x/2+4

Let's modify a bit the previous code as:

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch import optim
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 

# Define the NN model to solve the equation
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.lin1 = nn.Linear(1,10)
        self.lin2 = nn.Linear(10,1)

    def forward(self, x):
        y = torch.sigmoid(self.lin1(x))
        z = torch.sigmoid(self.lin2(y))
        return z

model = Model()

# Define loss_function from the Ordinary differential equation to solve
def ODE(x,fun):
    y = fun(x)

    dydx = torch.autograd.grad(y, x, 
    grad_outputs=y.data.new(y.shape).fill_(1),
    create_graph=True, retain_graph=True)[0]

    d2ydx2 = torch.autograd.grad(dydx, x, 
    grad_outputs=dydx.data.new(dydx.shape).fill_(1),
    create_graph=True, retain_graph=True)[0]

    eq  = d2ydx2 + torch.tensor([ 2.])             # y'' = - 2
    bc1 =  fun(torch.tensor([-2.])) - torch.tensor([-1.]) # y(x=-2) = -1
    bc2 =  fun(torch.tensor([ 2.])) - torch.tensor([ 1.]) # y(x= 2) =  1
    return torch.mean(eq**2) + bc1**2 + bc2**2

loss_func = ODE
```

So, here I passed the model as argument and managed to derive twice... so far so good. BUT, using the sigmoid function for this case is not only not necessary but also gives a result that is far from the analytical one.

If I change the NN for:

```py
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.lin1 = nn.Linear(1,1)
        self.lin2 = nn.Linear(1,1)

    def forward(self, x):
        y = self.lin1(x)
        z = self.lin2(y)
        return z
```

In which case I would expect to optimize a double pass through two linear functions that would retrieve a 2nd order function ... I get the error:

> RuntimeError: One of the differentiated Tensors appears to not have been used in the graph. Set allow_unused=True if this is the desired behavior.

Adding the option to the definition of dydx doesn't solve the problem, and adding it to d2ydx2 gives a NoneType definition.

Is there something wrong with the layers as they are?

Comment: See torch.autograd

Comment: @UmangGupta torch.autograd enables computing the gradient of a tensor w.r.t another tensor (as I did in dydx, = torch.autograd.grad(y, x, grad_outputs=y.data.new(y.shape).fill_(1), create_graph=True, retain_graph=True). What I'm looking for is a way of instantiating the gradient of a function (the model) in order to avoid passing as argument (input,output) but instead (input,function) ... Thanks!

Comment: isn't `output =fn (x)` ? so you can just compute it?

Comment: In principle yes, and it seems that it could work, but  I'm still getting a strange behavior as shown in the edit of the post. In the new definition I could either pass (x,y) or (x,fun) to the loss function, but I get a RunTime error with the target NN

Comment: The new code for `ODE` fn worked for me. Or can you show us the final code snippet that is not working?

Comment: I got the error when using the last definition of the NN with ```def forward(self, x):
        y = self.lin1(x)
        z = self.lin2(y)
        return z``` ... If I use the sigmoid just in the first one it works, but I don't understand why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick Solution:

add `allow_unused=True` to `.grad` functions. So, change

```
dydx = torch.autograd.grad(
    y, x,
    grad_outputs=y.data.new(y.shape).fill_(1),
    create_graph=True, retain_graph=True)[0]

d2ydx2 = torch.autograd.grad(dydx, x, grad_outputs=dydx.data.new(
    dydx.shape).fill_(1), create_graph=True, retain_graph=True)[0]
```

To

```
dydx = torch.autograd.grad(
    y, x,
    grad_outputs=y.data.new(y.shape).fill_(1),
    create_graph=True, retain_graph=True, allow_unused=True)[0]

d2ydx2 = torch.autograd.grad(dydx, x, grad_outputs=dydx.data.new(
    dydx.shape).fill_(1), create_graph=True, retain_graph=True, allow_unused=True)[0]
```

More explanation:

See what `allow_unused` do:

```
allow_unused (bool, optional): If ``False``, specifying inputs that were not
        used when computing outputs (and therefore their grad is always zero)
        is an error. Defaults to ``False``.
```

So, if you try to differentiate w.r.t to a variable that is not in being used to compute the value, it will give an error. Also, note that error only occurs when you use linear layers.

This is because when you use linear layers, you have `y=W1*W2*x + b = Wx+b` and `dy/dx` is not a function of `x`, it is simply `W`. So when you try to differentiate `dy/dx` w.r.t `x` it throws an error. This error goes away as soon as you use sigmoid because then `dy/dx` will be a function of `x`. To avoid the error, either make sure `dy/dx` is a function of x or use `allow_unused=True`

Comment: Yes thanks, you are right! so I found that if I use the sigmoid just for the first layer I get quite good results and for other problems as well! And in that case no need to add allow_unused=True